# Additional parameters in check_plain()

Tags: 7, views, navigation

I created link field in cck and add the URl like with apostrophe
**(https://www.sample.com/test's_data/test.pdf)**.

But the View output displayed as 
**(https://www.sample.com/test&#039s_data/test.pdf)**; As per the guidelines it is correct but my requirement is different. The URL points to a third party website it's rejecting with Access denied error message.

**How to prevent the single quotes to be transformed to html entities?**

**I'd prefer if check_plain has the another argument we can pass the flag as well !.**